# Coda - Plugin? Track Divs

Tags: html, plugins, coda

Does anyone know if there is a plugin for Coda that will show where a Div starts and ends?  I believe TextMate has this feature...

Solution:
Install TEA for Coda Plugin

Then do:
TEA for Coda > Select > Balanced Tag

Answer (score 2):

Yes, note that TEA for Coda is no longer maintained but Sergeche (on Github) has forked it, he's one of the guys behind Zencoding.

https://github.com/sergeche/tea-for-coda